# CSS: Position sticky vs fixed, why is width handled differently

Tags: html, css, css-position

Take the below CSS

```
.page-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 20;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

When applied to HTML

```
<header class="page-header">
  <span>Header - make me into a sticky header</span>
</header>
```

The width of the red bar is 100%.

When I use `position: fixed;` the header is only as wide as the content.

Why does Fixed behave differently?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Fixed is an absolutely positioned element which, unless you tell it otherwise will be the size of the contents. A sticky positioned element is treated as a relatively positioned element i.e. it treats the header as a block element which is, by default width: auto, i.e. full screen width. j09601 as provided the link to MDN. It's written in there under section "Types of Positioning"